# Python : struct module packing integer array

Tags: python, c

While packing struct, i usually do this

Suppose i have a structure like:

```
struct test {
unsigned int Id;
unsigned int Member1;
unsigned int Member2[2];  
unsigned int Member3[3];
};

test_values = (1,20,1,2,3,4,5)
vaultmap = struct.pack('IIIIIII',*test_values)
```

This approach is ok if the size of the array is small, but if it is a larger number say 512 , i find this approach as limiting as I have to say I 512 times and accordingly initialize the values. Is there any way to avoid this like we have for char.

if i have char sam[512] , we can use 512s , Some thing similar to this, I am looking for. I am using python 2.4

512I suggestion worked, but how should i initialize the array. I dont think i have to enter 512 integers like array_values = (1,1,1,1 ...... upto 512) there definitely should be some way to do that. If I use an array , I am getting error saying integer expected.

Comment: Use `struct.pack('I' * 256`, ...)?

Comment: Use the `array` module instead.

Answer (score 7):

In the `struct` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) there is a way to do it.

> A format character may be preceded by an integral repeat count. For example, the format string '4h' means exactly the same as 'hhhh'.

So in code- it will look like:

```
# test_values is a list of 512 integers
vaultmap = struct.pack('512I',*test_values)
```

Note however, that unlike strings, all 512 are independent numbers (not part of a single array). You could use python manipulation to treat them like array later.

> For the 's' format character, the count is interpreted as the size of the string, not a repeat count like for the other format characters;

Comment: Thanks That works, but then how can i initialize them. I have edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @user1512319: If you want a list of 512 ones, you can say `[1]*512`.

Comment: This works:

    `code`>>> struct.pack("3I", 1,1,1)
    '\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'
`code`
However i want to avoid giving 3 1's since my array may as big as 512                                                                   
`code`
    >>> struct.pack("3I", 3*[1])
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
    struct.error: required argument is not an integer `code`                                            Getting this error with this approach. I am looking to get around this. I am sure there should be a way, but i am not aware of it.

Comment: @user1512319: `struct.pack("3I", *(3*[1]))` (the same way you have `*test_values` in your question!)

Comment: Thanks Richie. That worked. But i have another problem related to this. `code` struct.pack('3I4s', *(3*[1]), "hai") or struct.pack('3II', *(3*[1]), 1) `code`. These snippets are not working. I did some googling and it seems this is not supported.

Comment: Upvoted. Note that if you have multiple chunks like this, you can put spaces as a visual aid to separate them. Ex: `512I 7Q 45B` instead of `512I7Q45B`, which is harder to read.